# Change output file format to *.csv using dymosim.exe instead of *.mat

Tags: executable, modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I am trying to understand if it's possible to change the model output format to ***.csv*** instead of the default **.mat** file when simulating a model using dymosim.exe.

I can do this in dymola itself by using the function "convertMATtoCSV" in the base Data files library. Something like below,

```
DataFiles.convertMATtoCSV("output.mat", {"t"}, "output.csv");
```

Is there a way to do this conversion using **dymosim.exe**?

Kindly advise.

Thanks.

Note: cmd "**dymosim.exe -h**" has some options for .csv but I am not sure how to use this.

Comment: You also used the tag `openmodelica`. How to change the output format to csv is described in the OpenModelica users guide: https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/introduction.html?highlight=csv#alternative-simulation-output-formats

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is currently not possible to have dymosim.exe generated by Dymola write the result as csv-file. The CSV-options used by dymosim.exe are only for  running multiple simulations.

You can:

- Generate a txt result instead, if that is easier to handle for you. (By setting Simulation Setup>Output>Textual data format, this is stored as last element of settings in dsin.txt).
- Perform the conversion using dymola\bin\alist.exe
- Have the model write a cvs-file as well
- Set up to perform this as a post-processing command in Dymola 2017 FD01.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Does "alist.exe" work without dymola license?

Comment: There are alist.exe binaries in bin, bin64 and in Mfiles. What is the difference between these three?